# Escaping quotes inside a quoted string

Tags: shell, escape-characters

I'm trying to run `curl` to POST JSON data with x-www-form-urlencode inside a `docker-compose` file.  For this example, I'm using this public website and I need to response to look like this

```
# sh -c 'curl http://httpbin.org/post -F "json={\"key\": \"value\"}"'
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "json": "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
  }, ...
```

That works fine with single quotes on the outside, but I need double quotes because I will have variables inside.  So this command does not work, and I can't figure out the right syntax for escaping the nested quotes.

```
# sh -c "curl http://httpbin.org/post -F "json={\"key\": \"$VAR\"}""
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "json": "{key:"
  },
```

Comment: `sh -c "curl http://httpbin.org/post -F \'json={\"key\": \"value\"}\'"`

Comment: Do you need the  `sh -c` there? I.e. can't just put `curl http://.. -F "whatever"` as the command? Because if you can drop the `sh -c`, you get to drop one set of quoting which makes it a lot easier.

Comment: @berndbausch, nope, `"... \' ..."` leaves both backslash and single-tick in the result, and you don't want that `sh -c` to see the single tick escaped.

Comment: Had I tested it, I would have written an answer. Might be better to compose the string one piece after the other, then hand it over to the shell. And true, why is `sh -c` needed?

Comment: The sub shell is required because it’s running the command line in a docker-compose script; there can only be one command.

Answer (score 2):

The data you want to insert into the argument sent to `curl` is a JSON-encoded string encoding a JSON document.

This string can be created separately like so:

```
json_string=$( jq -n --arg 'my key' 'my "value"' '$ARGS.named|@json' )
```

By using the JSON-aware tool `jq` to convert the data into a JSON-encoded string, we ensure that the contents of the string is both a valid JSON string and that it may be decoded into a valid JSON document containing the given key, `my key`, and value, `my "value"`.

The exact command above will assign the string `"{\"my key\":\"my \\\"value\\\"\"}"` to `json_string`.

We may then call `curl` directly using this string in an argument, like so,

```bash
curl 'http://httpbin.org/post' -F "json=$json_string"
```

... or, we may call it from an in-line `sh -c` script by passing the string as an argument to that script, like so,

```bash
sh -c 'curl "http://httpbin.org/post" -F "json=$1"' sh "$json_string"
```

Either of these ways of calling `curl` would result in a reply like the following:

```json
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "json": "{\"my key\":\"my \\\"value\\\"\"}"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "160",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------f805cf070f665e7e",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.84.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-83012651-2995681c270059da2906c40f"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

The encoding of the JSON document into a JSON string is not strictly necessary, as `curl` seems to be doing this on its own accord, so you could instead use

```bash
json_string=$( jq -n -c --arg 'my key' 'my "value"' '$ARGS.named' )
```

... to create the JSON string, or, if you happen to have `jo` installed, the shorter

```bash
json_string=$( jo 'my key'='my "value"' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```
$ var=hello
$ sh -c "curl http://httpbin.org/post -F 'json={\"key\": \"$var\"}'"
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "json": "{\"key\": \"hello\"}"
  },
```

Annotated:

```
$ sh -c "curl http://httpbin.org/post -F 'json={\"key\": \"$var\"}'"
        1                                2       3    3   34    3 21
```

(1) outer double-quoting, (2) single-quotes, *not* special within the double-quotes, so no need to escape, (3) inner double-quotes escaped for the outer ones. (4) variable expansion within the outer double-quotes, before running `sh -c` (note that single quotes within the variable value would cause issues for the inner shell, and double-quotes there would mess with the JSON syntax).

If `sh` is Bash, and you run that with `-x`, you'll see what it runs is this:

```
+ curl http://httpbin.org/post -F 'json={"key": "hello"}'
                                  2      3   3  3     3 2
```

which is pretty much exactly what that `sh -c` sees, and where, (2) is a quoted string, and (3) is non-special double-quotes within that string.

(I say "in Bash", because Dash's `set -x` output is not unambiguous. And in Bash, in general, the output from `-x` redoes quoting, e.g. if you give the command `echo "foo bar"`, it shows it as `echo 'foo bar'`. But that doesn't really change anything in this particular case.)

Answer (score 0):

Heredocs make this quoting hell much more manageable

```bsh
sh <<END_SCRIPT
curl http://httpbin.org/post -F 'json={"key": "$VAR"}'
END_SCRIPT
```

The heredoc itself is not quoted, so variables will be substituted.

If `VAR="foo bar"`, we get

```
...
  "form": {
    "json": "{\"key\": \"foo bar\"}"
  },
...
```

---

The only thing you'll have to worry about is if the variable value contains quotes.

With `VAR='She said "Hello"'` we see this invalid JSON

```
...
  "form": {
    "json": "{\"key\": \"She said \"Hello\"\"}"
  },
...
```

We can use shell parameter expansion to escape the inner quotes:

```bsh
sh <<END_SCRIPT
curl http://httpbin.org/post -F 'json={"key": "${VAR//\"/\\\"}"}'
END_SCRIPT
```

So that

```
...
  "form": {
    "json": "{\"key\": \"She said \\\"Hello\\\"\"}"
  },
...
```